# Prove the following : $ \int_0^{ 1 } \frac{x^{l-1} (1-x)^{m-1}}{ (b+cx)^{l+m} }\,dx = \frac{\beta(l,m)}{(b+c)^{l}b^m} $

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

> Prove the following : $$ \int_0^{ 1 } \frac{x^{l-1} (1-x)^{m-1}}{ (b+cx)^{l+m} }\,dx = \frac{\beta(l,m)}{(b+c)^{l}b^m} $$

I found this substitution :
$$ x = \frac{-b}{t+c} $$
Using this, we get the integral as
$$  \dfrac{{-1}^{l-1}}{b^m} \int_{-\infty}^{-b-c} \dfrac{(t+b+c)^{m-1}}{t^{l+m}}dt $$
Then on further substituting $ t+b+b = y$ and then $ y=-(b+c)x $  I got the integral as
$$   \dfrac{1}{(b+c)^{l}b^m} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{l+m}}dx =  \dfrac{\beta(l,m)}{(b+c)^{l}b^m} $$

Is there a better substitution to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Please update the answer with your ideas how to approach the problem...

Comment: Does $\beta(l,m)$ denote the Beta function?  And surely the upper limit is not $\pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, it does represent the beta function and the upper limit is 1, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Use the integral representation of the hypergeometric function then you can relate it to some famous functions.

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai Don't you think that 'integral representation of the hypergeometric function' is maybe a little difficult to understand for an undergraduate student without a reference ?

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles, please.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have no idea about his level, plus the beta function appears there as well.